# Android Studio cannot load Project

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating the newest Android studio,I cannot load project anymore.And the error message:

[image]

> Cannot load project:
>
> com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing 'com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'

I have tried to download it again,and reboot my system,it is not available. please help me.Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Recently I faced same issue where I was getting slightly different error related to XDebugger failure. It was because my project was in debug mode when I shutdown my laptop and intellij was not closed properly. It tends to try and find stored compiled classes again from cache when you start next time and when it could not find it from cache it just do not allow you to load full project.
Just Invalidate and restart option worked form.

**File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. It seems like there is something missing.Try to import your project new.
2. Or you press File->Invalidate Caches/Restart
3. Or restarting your laptop *works often (but you did as I know)
4. Or clear your cache and try to restart -> exit Android Studio->       Remove all the files in the cache directory`(home_dir/.AndroidStudio/system/cache)`->Then restart //but to prevent more erros :d safe them

Comment: I can't even go into the  development interface of the Android Studio.

Comment: After BSOD, bumped into this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Had some trouble with this one for a few weeks myself but in the end it turned out that the issue was actually with my Java_Home environment variable.  It was pointing to JRE1.8.etc  when it needed to be pointing to JDK1.8.0_101.

I probably just clicked on the wrong dl link or something, because when I downloaded jdk1.8 it replaced the jre file.  Then just update the environment variable by right clicking My Computer within the file explorer (for windows) then going to properties->advanced system settings->environment variables.  Then just edit your JAVA_HOME environment variable with the path of to where you installed the jdk (you can browse to it with file explorer then right click on the file path bar to copy the address and use CTRL+V to paste it).  Hope this helps.