# How to to create bug free android project

Tags: android

I'm new for android studio,when i create new project it gives error,so please help me

The error is

Fatal error initializing com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio cannot load Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370568/android-studio-cannot-load-project)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try deleting /Library/Java/Extensions directory
or
2) Restart your computer that may help you

Comment: sorry it can't help

Comment: As they have already given solution in this link -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370568/android-studio-cannot-load-project try this may help you out

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure your machine properly? Like, installing all requirements.
If so, have you try Clean, Rebuild, Make Project? This usually helps.
If so, did you made recent changes that leads to the error? Like, delete some unused classes.
If nothing above works, have you try create a new project? Try, this one also work for some cases.