# Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebuggerManager'

Tags: android-studio, centos7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz8ox.png)Just reinstall the my Android Studio and it give the an Error Message on StartUp

```
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebuggerManager'
```

Anybody understand why?

Comment: Do you have any non-bundled plugins installed?

Comment: It's a fresh install right out of the package.The problem is resolved by delete the /home/<username>/.AndroidStudio3/ folder and restart.but the question is why?

Comment: Non-bundled plugins are stored under ~/.AndroidStudio3 and are not removed if you reinstall Android Studio. Such an error can be caused by an incompatible plugin.

Answer (score 4):

try to close the Android Studio and open it again. that works for me (IntelliJ IDE with similar error: " Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebuggerManager' " )

if that not working try this: [Android Studio cannot load Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370568/android-studio-cannot-load-project)